# How to render a route in on the basis of some data

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I am new to the `react-redux`. Now here what I am doing is ,

In this, On click of login , and on the success of this ,

```
history.push('/');
```

I am redirecting user on this page.

Now,

```
import React from 'react';
import { fetchUserJd } from '../action/index';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { Redirect } from 'react-router-dom';
import JobList from '../../JobList/container/JobList';

class LandingPage extends React.Component {

  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.fetchJobDescription();
  }

  render() {
    if (this.props.jobs && this.props.jobs.content && this.props.jobs.content.length > 0) {
      return <JobList />;
    }
    else {
      return <Redirect to="/create-job" />
    }
  }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
  return {
    fetchJobDescription: () => dispatch(fetchUserJd())
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return {
    jobs: state.UserJobs.response
  }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(LandingPage);
```

Here this is my landing page.

Now, Here what I do is I call an api in the componentDidMount and get some data. If data is avaliable then I redirect user to some another page or to some diff route.

```
const initialState = {
    response: [],
    error: false
}

    case FETCHING_JOBDESCRIPTION_SUCCESS:
                return {
                    ...state,
                    response: action.data,
                    error: false,
                }
```

This is my reducer where I used the initial state as an empty array.

Now Here what is happening, it is directly going to the else condition to the `create-job` but the data is avaliable so it should have rendered that component. But, Somehow it is not happening.

Response is like =>

```
{
    "content": [{
        "id": "5b7d4a566c5fd00507501051",
        "hrmsJdId": null,
        "companyId": null,
        "jdName": "Senior/ Lead UI Developer",
        "jobDescription": null,
        }]


   }

render() {
    if (this.props.isFetching) {
        return null;
    }
    else if (this.props.jobs && this.props.jobs.content && this.props.jobs.content.length > 0) {
      return <JobList />;
    }
    else {
      return <Redirect to="/create-job" />
    }
  }
}
```

The solution that I used is like this ,

```
export function fetchUserJd() {
  return (dispatch) => {
    let url = FETCH_JD_ROOT_URL + page + "&" + size;
    dispatch({
      type: REQUEST_INITIATED
    })
    return get(url)
      .then((response) => {
        if (response.status === 200) {
          dispatch(
            {
              type: FETCHING_JOBDESCRIPTION_SUCCESS,
              data: response.payload
            }
          )
          dispatch({
            type: REQUEST_SUCCESSED
          })
        } else {
          dispatch({
            type: REQUEST_SUCCESSED
          })
        }
      })
  }
  return Promise.resolve();
};
```

So, Here I used `Promise.resolve` Now, in the componentDidMount,

in constructure,

```
 constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      isloading: true
    }
  }

componentDidMount() {
    this.props.fetchJobDescription().then(() => {
      this.setState({
        isloading: false
      })
    });
  }
```

SO, can any one please help me with this issue?

Comment: do you get any error, what is the structure for your `response` data

Comment: so the structure of the response is like,

Comment: I have just updated the question with response

Comment: The problem is that you make an api call in componentDidMount, and when you render you don't have `jobs` hence it goes to the else part which redirects, what you  need is a loading state

Comment: Actually, I do have one props as a this.props.isFetching  that is when we are fetching some data

Comment: How do I use that prop over here

Comment: In render show a loader or return null if , `this.props.isFetching` is set to `true`

Comment: What is happening for some time it becomes false so then it renders the else part

Comment: Added the way I tried

Comment: You should maintain the loading flag for jobDescription api itself and not share it among different apis

Comment: Actually I am a bit confused how to use local state fetching with the api call. Should I use a reducer or the local state

Comment: you should render a loader while data are being fetched and when fecthed re-render the component with fetched data or redirect to create-job route if no jobs are found

Comment: Actually for that I am a bit confused How to use that local-state as I will set it as a true initially and then Do I have to use the receiverProps to make it false so that the other part will get rendered

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri I have just updated my question with my answer please check weather it can be a good solution or not

Comment: return after a return will never be exxecuted you should instead return a promise and resolve it in `.then`

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri Could you please add a little bit as a answer I am getting a bit confused